# R remove first row of data frame until first row has no NA

Tags: r, function, dataframe, while-loop, na

I am applying na.approx on a data frame, which will not work if an NA happens to be in the very first or very last row of my data base.

How do I write a function doing the following:
"While any value of the first row of the data frame is NA, remove the first row"

Example data frame:

```
x1=x2=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
x3=x4=c(NA,NA,3,4,5,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,11,12)
df=data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

result for this example data frame should look like this:

```
result=df[-1:-2,]
```

My current attempts all look similar to this:

```
replace_na=function(df){
while(anyNA(df[1,])=TRUE){
  df=df[-1,],
  return(df)
}  
#this is where I would apply the na.approx function to the data frame
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Psidom's answer is great, but you can also fix your own custom function:

```
replace_na=function(df){
   while(anyNA(df[1,])==TRUE){
      df=df[-1,]
   }
#this is where I would apply the na.approx function to the data frame
return(df)
}
```

On its second line, `==` is the equal sign you need to use. On the second line, comma was superfluous. And last, `return()` needed to be moved out of the `while` loop.

```
replace_na(df)
#    x1 x2 x3 x4
# 3   3  3  3  3
# 4   4  4  4  4
# 5   5  5  5  5
# 6   6  6  6  6
# 7   7  7 NA NA
# 8   8  8 NA NA
# 9   9  9 NA NA
# 10 10 10 NA NA
# 11 11 11 11 11
# 12 12 12 12 12
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `complete.cases`. With the `cumsum`, first incomplete rows will be deleted:

```
df[cumsum(complete.cases(df)) != 0, ]
   x1 x2 x3 x4
3   3  3  3  3
4   4  4  4  4
5   5  5  5  5
6   6  6  6  6
7   7  7 NA NA
8   8  8 NA NA
9   9  9 NA NA
10 10 10 NA NA
11 11 11 11 11
12 12 12 12 12
```

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds. ... oh well.

Comment: thank you for your solution, will be very helpful for many other users and worked for me too. I chose the other answer because it fixes my messy code and it's easier to apply to my second step (do the same for last rows)

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `which.max` and `is.na`

```
df[which.max(!rowSums(is.na(df))):nrow(df),]
#   x1 x2 x3 x4
#3   3  3  3  3
#4   4  4  4  4
#5   5  5  5  5
#6   6  6  6  6
#7   7  7 NA NA
#8   8  8 NA NA
#9   9  9 NA NA
#10 10 10 NA NA
#11 11 11 11 11
#12 12 12 12 12
```