# Remove last row of data frame until reaching a row that does not have an NA

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a dataframe that contains `NA` values, and I want to remove some rows that have an `NA` (i.e., not complete cases). However, I only want to remove rows at the end of the dataframe. So, I want to keep any rows that have an `NA` that are not at the end of the dataframe. What is the most efficient way to remove the ending rows with `NA`s without using a row index?

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = 1:15, var2 = c(3, 6, 3, NA, 2, NA, 3, 4, 
2, NA, 4, 2, 45, 2, 1), var3 = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, NA, NA, NA, NA), var4 = c(NA, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

**Expected Output**

So, in this example, I removed rows 12 through 15 since they have an `NA` and row 11 does not have an `NA`.

```
   var1 var2 var3 var4
1     1    3    6   NA
2     2    6    7    7
3     3    3    8    8
4     4   NA    9    9
5     5    2   10   10
6     6   NA   11   11
7     7    3   12   12
8     8    4   13   13
9     9    2   14   14
10   10   NA   15   15
11   11    4   16   16
```

I could [remove the first rows of a dataframe with NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843012/r-remove-first-row-of-data-frame-until-first-row-has-no-na) by:

```
df[cumsum(complete.cases(df)) != 0,]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `na.trim` from `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  slice(1:nrow(na.trim(df, "right", is.na = "any")))
```

```
   var1 var2 var3 var4
1     1    3    6   NA
2     2    6    7    7
3     3    3    8    8
4     4   NA    9    9
5     5    2   10   10
6     6   NA   11   11
7     7    3   12   12
8     8    4   13   13
9     9    2   14   14
10   10   NA   15   15
11   11    4   16   16
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last rows, you can use `rev` in the same approach. So, we put the output from `complete.cases` in reverse order, so that we can calculate `cumsum` starting with the end of the dataframe. Then, we put the `cumsum` back in the original order (the reason for the second `rev`). Now, we can remove the rows with `0` (i.e., rows that contain an `NA`).

```
df[rev(cumsum(rev(complete.cases(df)))) != 0,]
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(rev(cumsum(rev(complete.cases(.)))) != 0)
```

**Output**

```
   var1 var2 var3 var4
1     1    3    6   NA
2     2    6    7    7
3     3    3    8    8
4     4   NA    9    9
5     5    2   10   10
6     6   NA   11   11
7     7    3   12   12
8     8    4   13   13
9     9    2   14   14
10   10   NA   15   15
11   11    4   16   16
```

Answer (score 0):

Tortured and possibly only applicable in this instance where max fortuitously coincides with last rows:

```
df2[1:(length(df2[,1])-max(rle(complete.cases(df2))$lengths)),]
   var1 var2 var3 var4
1     1    3    6   NA
2     2    6    7    7
3     3    3    8    8
4     4   NA    9    9
5     5    2   10   10
6     6   NA   11   11
7     7    3   12   12
8     8    4   13   13
9     9    2   14   14
10   10   NA   15   15
11   11    4   16   16
```