# Simultaneously remove the first and last rows of a data frame until reaching a row that does not have an NA

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, tidyverse, na

I have a dataframe that contains `NA` values, and I want to remove some rows that have an `NA` (i.e., not complete cases). However, I only want to remove rows at the beginning and ending of the dataframe. So, I want to keep any rows that have an `NA` that are not in the first or last rows of the dataframe. What is the most efficient way to simultaneously remove these rows with `NA`s without using a row index? This is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71756173/15293191), but I also want to remove the first rows at the same time. There are other posts that also focus on [removing only the first rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843012/r-remove-first-row-of-data-frame-until-first-row-has-no-na), but not both.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = 1:15, 
                     var2 = c(3, NA, 3, NA, 2, NA, 3, 4, 2, NA, 4, 2, 45, 2, 1), 
                     var3 = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                     var4 = c(NA, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, NA)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

**Expected Output**

So, in this example, I removed rows 1 to 2, and 12 to 15 since they have an `NA` and row 3 and 11 does not have an `NA`.

```
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    3    3    8    8
2    4   NA    9    9
3    5    2   10   10
4    6   NA   11   11
5    7    3   12   12
6    8    4   13   13
7    9    2   14   14
8   10   NA   15   15
9   11    4   16   16
```

I know that I could have 2 statements in filter to remove the top and bottom rows (shown below). But I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this with really large datasets (open to any method `tidyverse`, base R, `data.table`, etc.).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(cumsum(complete.cases(.)) != 0 & 
           rev(cumsum(rev(complete.cases(.)))) != 0)
```

Comment: Large table with variable 1:n contain NA and m:Last contain NA?

Comment: And a faux large representative table that we might benchmark these various approaches? With your code for the table, as I think this 'representative' data is extremely useful toward MRE, but I know I'm not there yet.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, great suggestion! I've added a large ample dataset (down below) and ran a benchmark on the existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base R

```r
r <- rle(complete.cases(df))
str(r, vec.len = 9)
# List of 2
#  $ lengths: int [1:9] 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 4
#  $ values : logi [1:9] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "rle"
r$values[ -c(1, length(r$values)) ] <- TRUE
str(r, vec.len = 9)
# List of 2
#  $ lengths: int [1:9] 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 4
#  $ values : logi [1:9] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "rle"
df[inverse.rle(r),]
#    var1 var2 var3 var4
# 3     3    3    8    8
# 4     4   NA    9    9
# 5     5    2   10   10
# 6     6   NA   11   11
# 7     7    3   12   12
# 8     8    4   13   13
# 9     9    2   14   14
# 10   10   NA   15   15
# 11   11    4   16   16
```

### dplyr

For your question of efficiency, you can adapt the `rle` solution to dplyr as well (that should be trivial), but I see no reason why the use of `complete.cases` and `cumany`/`rev` would be a problem. You can improve on your attempt by not calculating `complete.cases(.)` *twice* as you're doing, storing it in an interim column.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(aux = complete.cases(cur_data())) %>%
  filter(cumany(aux) & rev(cumany(rev(aux))))
#   var1 var2 var3 var4   aux
# 1    3    3    8    8  TRUE
# 2    4   NA    9    9 FALSE
# 3    5    2   10   10  TRUE
# 4    6   NA   11   11 FALSE
# 5    7    3   12   12  TRUE
# 6    8    4   13   13  TRUE
# 7    9    2   14   14  TRUE
# 8   10   NA   15   15 FALSE
# 9   11    4   16   16  TRUE
```

### data.table

(Just an adaptation of the dplyr version.)

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, aux := complete.cases(.SD)
  ][ cumsum(aux) > 0 & rev(cumsum(rev(aux)) > 0), ]
#     var1  var2  var3  var4    aux
#    <int> <num> <int> <int> <lgcl>
# 1:     3     3     8     8   TRUE
# 2:     4    NA     9     9  FALSE
# 3:     5     2    10    10   TRUE
# 4:     6    NA    11    11  FALSE
# 5:     7     3    12    12   TRUE
# 6:     8     4    13    13   TRUE
# 7:     9     2    14    14   TRUE
# 8:    10    NA    15    15  FALSE
# 9:    11     4    16    16   TRUE
```

Comment: alternatively we could subset from the first TRUE till the last TRUE of the complete cases: `df[, aux := complete.cases(.SD)][first(which(aux)):last(which(aux))]`

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg Interesting! I updated the benchmark and it looks like this is the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
na_count <- rowSums(is.na(df))
df <- df %>%
  slice(min(which(na_count==0)):max(which(na_count==0)))
```

Output

```
> df
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    3    3    8    8
2    4   NA    9    9
3    5    2   10   10
4    6   NA   11   11
5    7    3   12   12
6    8    4   13   13
7    9    2   14   14
8   10   NA   15   15
9   11    4   16   16
```

Answer (score 2):

I think we overcomplicated it a bit, most efficient I think is just plain base R

Directly take all your complete cases

```
s <- which(complete.cases(df))
```

We surely cannot subset on s, as we want to keep all the "in between" incomplete ones too, we can achieve that by simply subset from the first up till the last index.

```
df[first(s):last(s), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

continuing a `rle` love fest:

```
(which(rle(rowSums(df_NA))$values != 'NA')[1]):dplyr::last(which(rle(rowSums(df_NA))$values != 'NA'))
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

or, dispensing with `dplyr`

```
(which(rle(rowSums(df_NA))$values != 'NA')[1]):(which(rle(rowSums(df_NA))$values != 'NA'))[[(length(which(rle(rowSums(df_NA))$values != 'NA')))]]
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution (thanks, @r2evans, for suggesting `complete.cases`):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(aux = !complete.cases(.)) %>% 
  filter(!cumall(aux)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(var1)) %>% 
  filter(!cumall(aux)) %>%
  arrange(var1) %>% 
  select(-aux)

#>   var1 var2 var3 var4
#> 1    3    3    8    8
#> 2    4   NA    9    9
#> 3    5    2   10   10
#> 4    6   NA   11   11
#> 5    7    3   12   12
#> 6    8    4   13   13
#> 7    9    2   14   14
#> 8   10   NA   15   15
#> 9   11    4   16   16
```

Comment: I suggest this would work just as well with `complete.cases(.)` while being immune from the real data having a non-numeric column (for this OP or a more generic sense). (It's also a lot more efficient for this type of operation.)

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans, for having commented my solution. I have updated it according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but base R in a single expression:

```
df[Reduce(
  function(x, y){
    seq(from = x, to = y)
  },
  range(
    which(
    complete.cases(df)
    )
  )
), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Benchmark**

Here, I create a bigger dataset with 1,000,000 million rows of 3 variables to determine which method is the fastest. *Note: It will take a few seconds to apply the `NA` values randomly to the 3 columns for the first 100,000 rows and the last 100,000 rows. Essentially, with this example, we want to remove the first 100,000 rows and the last 100,000 rows.

*Dataset*

```
set.seed(203)
df <- data.frame(var1 = sample(x = 1:500, size = 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                 var2 = sample(x = 1:500, size = 1000000, replace = TRUE),
                 var3 = sample(x = 1:500, size = 1000000, replace = TRUE))
df[1:100000,] <- plyr::ddply(df[1:100000,], .(var1, var2, var3), function(x) {x[sample(x = 1:3, size = 1, replace = TRUE)] <- NA;x})
df[900000:1000000,] <- plyr::ddply(df[900000:1000000,], .(var1, var2, var3), function(x) {x[sample(x = 1:3, size = 1, replace = TRUE)] <- NA;x})
df[300000:400000,2] <- NA
```

*Output*

[image]

It looks like @MerijnvanTilborg `data.table` solution is the fastest, followed by @r2evans `data.table` version on this sample dataset.

*Code*

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df1 <- df
dt1 <- as.data.table(df)
dt2 <- as.data.table(df)

bm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(baseR_r2evans = {r <- rle(complete.cases(df1)); 
r$values[ -c(1, length(r$values)) ] <- TRUE; df[inverse.rle(r),]},
dplyr_r2evans = {df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(aux = complete.cases(cur_data())) %>%
    dplyr::filter(cumany(aux) & rev(cumany(rev(aux))))},
datatable_r2evans = {dt1[, aux := complete.cases(.SD)
][ cumsum(aux) > 0 & rev(cumsum(rev(aux)) > 0), ]},
valkyr = {na_count <- rowSums(is.na(df)); df %>%
  dplyr::slice(min(which(na_count==0)):max(which(na_count==0)))},
PaulS = {df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(aux = !complete.cases(.)) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(!cumall(aux)) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(desc(var1)) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(!cumall(aux)) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(var1) %>% 
    dplyr::select(-aux)},
Chris = {df[(which(rle(rowSums(df))$values != 'NA')[1]):(which(rle(rowSums(df))$values != 'NA'))[[(length(which(rle(rowSums(df))$values != 'NA')))]],]},
AndrewGB = {df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(cumsum(complete.cases(.)) != 0 & 
                    rev(cumsum(rev(complete.cases(.)))) != 0)},
Merijn_baseR = {s <- which(complete.cases(df)); 
df[first(s):last(s), ]},
Merijn_datatable = {dt2[, aux := complete.cases(.SD)][first(which(aux)):last(which(aux))]},
times = 1000
)
```